# Read Data From Wireless Weigh Scale

Tags: vb.net

i want to read data from wireless weigh scale using vb.net program which is connected to wireless router and router connected via LAN to computer i can ping it and also can read data continuously to web browser but unable to get data in program.

I have tried to read data using websocket with javascript and i got result.In my windows application i added one web browser control and created one javascript function which read data from device using websocket. but problem is that i am getting result in alert message but  i am unable to save it or insert into database.

Following is VB.NET code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cDir As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(Path.Combine(cDir & "\Function.html"))
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Try
        WebBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = Me
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("returnData")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Sub ShowMessage(ByVal obj As Object)
    MsgBox(obj)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(obj)
End Sub
```

Following is JavaScript Function:

```
function returnData(){
    var Socket;
    Socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + "192.168.2.10" + ":81/"); 
    Socket.onmessage = function(evt){
    alert(evt.data);
    <!-- return window.external.ShowMessage(evt.data); -->
}
```

Comment: Hello could you please take the time to take the [tour] and to read [ask] and to try and follow the [mcve]

Comment: @Mederic i have already took that

Comment: If you had looked that you would have given code or more details and showed us what you have done as mentionned in [mcve]

Comment: @Mederic i know that i have code that read data through RS232 Port and in web browser it does not need any code directly i can read using ip, would you like to see RS232 port code?

Comment: You still didn't post any examples! You really should read [mcve] as mentionned: `Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. ` and also seems you still didnt read it: `Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem!`

Comment: As suggested, "I want to do this, tell me how" is not an appropriate question for this site. This site is for specific issues. If you don't know how to do something then you need to learn how first, then try, then post here if you encounter an issue doing so. In this case, the manufacturer's web site should be the first port of call for how to use their product. They will almost certainly have a section for developers with instructions and/or examples.

Comment: @Mederic i have added code

Comment: @jmcilhinney i tried to do that and i got this

Comment: Why do you create a webbrowser to execute a socket connection instead of directly connection to the socket? please try to follow this guide: https://binary.vanillacommunity.com/discussion/72/connection-code-to-websocket-using-vb-net

Comment: @Mederic i tried thr guide which you just gave to me as first solution but i was not receiving any data